# Getting a second window pass a variable to the main ui and close

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdialog

I'm trying to get a variable selected from the list to be sent back to the main window and then close the second window when the ok button is pressed. Currently the second window will not close. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
class select_variable_window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, list, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 251, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label=QLabel("Select Variable for Scatterplot", self)

        self.dialogbutton = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self)
        self.dialogbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 260, 161, 32))
        self.dialogbutton.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.dialogbutton.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.dialogbutton.setObjectName("dialogbutton")

        self.variablelist = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        self.variablelist.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 391, 221))
        self.variablelist.setObjectName("variablelist")
        self.variablelist.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.variablelist.addItems(list)

        self.dialogbutton.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.dialogbutton.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def accept(self):
        self.scattervariable=[item.text() for item in self.variablelist.selectedItems()]
        print(self.scattervariable)
        self.close()# wont close
        return

    def reject(self):
        self.close()#wont close
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all do not use list as the name of a variable since it is a reserved word, and doing so is considered a bad practice that in the future can bring problems.

On the other hand `accept()` is a method that closes the window and gives the return code `QDialog.Accepted`, but you are overwriting it and preventing it from doing its job, so after doing your logic you have to call the method of the parent to do his typical closing and establish a return code.

On the other hand, it is recommended that the names of the classes begin with capital letters, read the PEP8 for more information. On the other hand I recommend learning to use layouts to establish the position of element.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Select_variable_window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, items, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Select Variable for Scatterplot:")

        self.variablelist = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.variablelist.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.variablelist.addItems(items)

        dialogbutton = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox()
        dialogbutton.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        dialogbutton.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)

        lay.addWidget(label)
        lay.addWidget(self.variablelist)
        lay.addWidget(dialogbutton)

        dialogbutton.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        dialogbutton.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def accept(self):
        self.scattervariable = [item.text() for item in self.variablelist.selectedItems()]
        super().accept() # <-- call parent method


class FirstWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Open Dialog")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        lay.addWidget(button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        w = Select_variable_window(["1", "2", "3", "4"])
        if w.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            print(w.scattervariable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = FirstWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```